# Release BSTR returned from recordset or not

Tags: mfc, com, ado

Got some ADODB code here which retrieves a BSTR from a record set, but Im not sure whether the BSTR should be released with SysFreeString or not. Right now it is and it seems to be working but should you do that yourself?

```
    BSTR bstr = m_pRecordset->Fields->GetItem ( field )->Value.bstrVal;

    int len = SysStringLen(bstr);

    while (len > 0 && iswspace(bstr[len-1])) len--;

    BSTR newstr = SysAllocStringLen(bstr, len);

    SysFreeString(bstr);
    SysFreeString(newstr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. `m_pRecordset->Fields->GetItem ( field )->Value` returns a `VARIANT` as `_variant_t`.

You should save the object in a temporary variable, access the data and the destructor will do the rest.

```
_variant_t val = m_pRecordset->Fields->GetItem ( field )->Value;

int len = SysStringLen(val.bstrVal);

while (len > 0 && iswspace(bstr[len-1])) len--;

BSTR newstr = SysAllocStringLen(val.bstrVal, len);
...
SysFreeString(newstr);
```

[See sample here in the MSDN.](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/item-property-example-vc?view=sql-server-2017)

Also it should be mentioned that it would be better to use `CComBSTR` or `_bstr_t` instead of BSTR.

Comment: When you use the code that's generated by Visual C++ and not the raw COM interfaces, you shall never use BSTR nor VARIANT anymore, but always use _bstr_t and _variant_t, and (almost) forget about releasing memory since they are smart wrapper classes as you know. So, in your code, I would not use BSTR and not use SysFreeString. Also, your link points to german docs :-)

Comment: @sim: I was going to suggest using [_bstr_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-class) as well, although I'm not sure how you'd use it here. While it has a c'tor taking a `variant_t&`, the object constructed is strictly immutable, and there doesn't appear to be any way, to construct a `_bstr_t` over a subrange of another `_bstr_t`/`wchar_t[]`/`BSTR`.

Comment: @IInspectable - I was just talking about the newstr variable, it could be a _bstr_t instead of a BSTR

Comment: You are right. I just used the code as the user wrote it... _bstr_t is much better here too!

Comment: Using a [CComBSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class) is probably more appropriate here, as it provides a [c'tor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class#ccombstr) taking an explicit length argument.

Comment: @sim: I know, but how do you construct a `_bstr_t` from a pointer **and size**?